# laravel 8 gives default 404 error when requested via curl

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

This next thing is driving me crazy for a couple of days now.

*The case:*
My Laravel (8) app is hosted on AWS. When I go to the site by browsing to it, it loads. But the health check of AWS is giving `404` errors. Resulting in a never finishing code pipeline, bacause of deployment failure. That leaded to do some debugging. And it seems that whenever I load the page by curl it gives me the Laravel `404` page.

*What I tried:*

- My `web.php` has a fallback to the `/home` route, so it should never ever load the `404` page of Laravel. And yes, the controller exists and is returning an existing view.
- I created a very simple response for the route `/health` which should give plain text `status:ok;` with a `200` HTTP status code.

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/health', function() {
    return response('status:ok;', 200);
});

Route::get('/home', [Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::fallback(function() { return redirect()->route('home'); });
```

**Browsing to the url (in Chrome)**
[image]

**Curl testing**

```
curl "127.0.0.1/health"
```

*response:*

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Where is my page!?</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? It is really driving me crazy! I 've created dozens of Laravel apps, but never hosted on AWS which reveals this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it show up when you do `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @sohailamar It seems that the route contained an error that wasn't showing up in the logs. But it did when I ran your command. I'm commiting my changes now to see if that fixes the problem. Thanks for the quick hint!

Comment: @sohailamar unfortunately, that was not the solution. Even if I fixed the error in the route. BUT now it IS loading the custom 404. Yet, still a 404...

Comment: have you tried `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: @sohailamar Yes, I've tried to clear te caches of everything and even cache them again (which is giving no errors).

Comment: Can you try by updating the route like this.
`Route::any('/health', function() {
    return response('status:ok;', 200);
});`

Comment: @sohailamar Unfortunately, this is not the solution. When I check with SSH:  
`curl 127.0.0.1/health`  

Returns the custom 404 page.